# Job not scrolling to specific text on a webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scroll, web-scraping

I have a job that works perfectly except for scrolling to this element: `//span[text()="Next Page"]` on this [page](https://pastebin.com/47yC189y).

When I manually scroll, it tends to work.

What I have tried to address scrolling to this text:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

As well as:

```
clickMe = wait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//span[text()="Next Page"]'))))
clickMe2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(clickMe2).click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe2)
```

It goes through the job and then gives an error at the following line:  `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe2)`

Full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Bain3/PycharmProjects/untitled4/Crownbet.py", line 2674, in <module>
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", clickMe2)
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 532, in execute_script
    'args': converted_args})['value']
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Bain3\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: arguments[0].scrollIntoView is not a function
  (Session info: chrome=61.0.3163.100)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.31.488763 (092de99f48a300323ecf8c2a4e2e7cab51de5ba8),platform=Windows NT 10.0.15063 x86_64)
```

Full [code](https://pastebin.com/47yC189y)

*UPDATED*.

I have removed this from earlier on:

```
#SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5


#last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

#while True:

    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")


    #time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)


    #new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    #if new_height == last_height:
        #break
    #last_height = new_height
```

However, it seems to scroll the entire page rather than to that specific element.  This is with:

```
clickMe = wait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, ('//span[text()="Next Page"]'))))
element1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you're scrolling right to required element, but there is a navigation panel (the one with Search bar, Login and Join Now buttons) which is fixed at the top and overplapped the Next button. You just need to scroll up a little to make Next button visible. Try below code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

header = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('header')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[text()="Next Page"]')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.UP)
element.click()
```

Comment: Hmm still seems unclickable for me: lenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <span class="show-next pager-button" data-page="1">...</span> is not clickable at point (883, 31). Other element would receive the click: <button class="login-flyout-button__title">...</

Comment: Try `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.UP + Keys.UP)` instead of just `driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.UP)`

Comment: Seems to work when I add time.sleep.  HMM is there a wait for scroll up or something similar command.

Comment: Hmm... You can try `wait(driver, 5).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//span[text()="Next Page"]')))`

Comment: You can also try just to hide header :) call this `header = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('header')` and this `driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header)` right before the code I've provided

Comment: Getting really weird output with this job selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document 
      https://pastebin.com/1bbgkgQr  .  Do you think this is scrolling or wait issue...

Comment: OO     driver.execute_script('arguments[0].hidden="true";', header  might address the issue.   I am getting NameError: name 'header' is not defined.

Comment: did you define `header` as `header = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('header')`?

Comment: Awesome! That worked.  Although it does tend to not write the entire data to a row and gives error at print(lang.text).  HMM https://pastebin.com/uxqeNcK0 , https://ibb.co/i1EjD6

Comment: Hmm, it is very finicky.  Getting Other element would receive the click: <table class="sport-event-table">...</table>.

Comment: I'll do some further bug testing for that separate issue.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below code:-

```
targetElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("your xpath"));
JavascriptExecutor js = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver);
// This:
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", targetElement);
targetElement.click();
// Or maybe even just:
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", targetElement);
```

Comment: JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Andersson Any ideas why this issue is being caused.  I did get it to scroll eventually though it seems to scroll well and truly past the element I need and gives an error code as a result